# How to calculate mean base on quantile for one of the column

Tags: r, for-loop

Let say I want to find out the mean for other column group by the another column quantile.

For my table, I have several columns, now I got the 10% quantile for SalePrice column, there are some other numeric columns in my table(there are also some other factor variables in this table to).

And I want to calculate these variables' mean group by SalePrice column.

Then after that, I want to save these result in to a data frame.

I want to use loop to construct this data frame, I have some basic idea about the loop, but don't know how to finish it. Or add the column in the data frame in the loop

```
for (i in 1:lenth(tr)){
  if(tr$i == numeric){
    Result <- data.frame()
  }
}
```

here is what I got for the SalePrice 10% quantile

```
> quantile(tr$SalePrice, c(seq(0, 1,0.1)),na.rm = TRUE, names = TRUE)
    0%    10%    20%    30%    40%    50%    60%    70%    80%    90%   100% 
 34900 106450 124000 135500 147000 163000 179360 198740 230000 278000 755000
```

And my data look like this:

```
> dput(head(tr, 5))
structure(list(
MSSubClass = structure(c(6L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("20", "30", "40", "45", "50", "60", "70", "75", "80", "85", "90", "120", "160", "180", "190"), class = "factor"), 

MSZoning = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("C (all)", "FV", "RH", "RL", "RM"), class = "factor"), 

LotFrontage = c(65, 80, 68, 60, 84), 

LotArea = c(8450, 9600, 11250, 9550, 14260), 

Street = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Grvl", "Pave"), class = "factor"), 

Alley = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Grvl", "NA", "Pave"), class = "factor"), 

LotShape = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("IR1", "IR2", "IR3", "Reg"), class = "factor"), 

LandContour = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Bnk", "HLS", "Low", "Lvl"), class = "factor"), 

Utilities = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AllPub", "NoSeWa"), class = "factor"), 

LotConfig = structure(c(5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Corner", "CulDSac", "FR2", "FR3", "Inside"), class = "factor"), 

LandSlope = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Gtl", "Mod", "Sev"), class = "factor"), 

Neighborhood = structure(c(6L, 25L, 6L, 7L, 14L), .Label = c("Blmngtn", "Blueste", "BrDale", "BrkSide", "ClearCr", "CollgCr", "Crawfor", "Edwards", "Gilbert", "IDOTRR", "MeadowV", "Mitchel", "NAmes", "NoRidge", "NPkVill", "NridgHt", "NWAmes", "OldTown", "Sawyer", "SawyerW", "Somerst", "StoneBr", "SWISU", "Timber", "Veenker"), class = "factor"), 

Condition1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Artery", "Feedr", "Norm", "PosA", "PosN", "RRAe", "RRAn", "RRNe", "RRNn"), class = "factor"), 

Condition2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Artery", "Feedr", "Norm", "PosA", "PosN", "RRAe", "RRAn", "RRNn"), class = "factor"), 

BldgType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1Fam", "2fmCon", "Duplex", "Twnhs","TwnhsE"), class = "factor"),

SalePrice = c(208500, 181500, 223500, 140000, 250000)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I only attach some variables here, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any data so I was left making a few assumptions. Assuming that your data is called `df` perhaps you can use `dput(head(df, 100))` and copy and paste the output here?

If not does this work for you?

```
d1 <- runif(1000)
d2 <- runif(1000)
d3 <- runif(1000)


df <- data.frame(SalePrice = d1,
                 data2 = d2,
                 data3 = d3)

library(dplyr)


df %>%
  mutate(Mydeciles = ntile(data2, 10)) %>%
  group_by(Mydeciles) %>%
  summarise(mean_sales_price = mean(SalePrice),
            mean_data2 = mean(data2),
            mean_data3 = mean(data3))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Mydeciles mean_sales_price mean_data2 mean_data3
       <int>            <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         1            0.497     0.0450      0.450
 2         2            0.520     0.144       0.522
 3         3            0.506     0.250       0.487
 4         4            0.472     0.360       0.457
 5         5            0.510     0.469       0.553
 6         6            0.555     0.564       0.503
 7         7            0.510     0.652       0.540
 8         8            0.461     0.751       0.482
 9         9            0.465     0.844       0.485
10        10            0.530     0.952       0.534
```

---

Solution 2:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Mydeciles = ntile(SalePrice, 2)) %>%
  group_by(Mydeciles) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean))
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Mydeciles LotFrontage LotArea SalePrice
      <int>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1         1        68.3    9200   176667.
2         2        76     12755   236750
```

Comment: I have attached my data, and I want to use loop since i do not know which variable is numeric, but I want loop to find it out and calculate the mean

Comment: I added a new solution.

Comment: could you please use loop to do it, since I have too many variables, and I am not able to find the numeric variables by myself. I want to use loop to find it

Comment: the `summarise_if` part of the function only applies the `mean` calculation if the vairable `is.numeric`. The sample data you provided included factor variables and 3 numeric variables which is the output.

Comment: But ```ntile()``` do not return the group base on the 10% quantiles right?

Comment: You only supplied 5 observations, change the `2` to `10` and it should compute deciles.

Answer (score 0):

A data.table answer:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[,  .(mean_price = mean(salesPrice), mean_r1 = mean(data1), mean_r2 = mean(data2)), by = .(qtl = quantile(salesPrice, seq(0, 1, 0.1)))]
```